# As Android Studio 3.0.1 doesnt support a lot of things, for API lower than 21. Downgrade to 2.3.1

Tags: android, memory

Unfortunately, I've updated Android Studio from 2.3.1 to 3.0.1 but they destroy a lot of things in it (it doesn't support all profiling for API lower than 21).   How to downgrade it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just uninstall 3.0.1 and reinstall 2.3.3?

Download old versions of Android studio from the link here.
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Comment: This is what I had to do.

Comment: If it works, please up vote and accept the answer. Thanks!